# using validation rules child field should be automatically updated by parent field

Tags: validation

i want to populate child field value automatically from parent field value by validation rules for ex: in Account object country field should automatically populated in Contacts country field

please advise

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Process Builder to build processes that update child records, as in the case of your example with Accounts and Contacts

[See https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_action_update.htm&language=en_US](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_action_update.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i need to do it using validation rules, is this can be done by validations

Comment: Do you perhaps mean prepopulating values when creating child objects based on values of the parent object? So you are inserting a Contact and want to autopopulate the country field based on the Account country field? 

Either way, this isn't for validation rules as @anshul says.

Answer (score 2):

Validation rules are to be created to validate data only and stop dml operations (insert/update) if data doesn't comply business rules. It cannot be used to update data in records.

In order to update field on child records you can use process builder or apex triggers. (Alternatively, for new child records you can also use formula based default values for fields https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_default_field_values.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: thanks for the info can you please tell me how many validations rules can be crated on one object

Comment: that varies based on editions. You can find details at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US